# How do you do a HTTP POST with digest authentication in Golang?

Tags: http, authentication, go, gerrit

I am trying to use the [Gerrit API](https://gerrit-review.googlesource.com/Documentation/rest-api.html#authentication) that requires digest authentication. After reading up some I know I am supposed to make a request, get a 401, then use the realm and nonce and maybe other headers to then create the actual request authentication using MD5. I have found some examples on digest but they all seem to be the server side, not the client side.

Comment: Every request I made just gave me a 401. I figure out how to make the request and will add an answer now.

Comment: Here's a package which makes this relatively simple: https://github.com/icholy/digest

Answer (score 17):

I mostly followed what [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digest_access_authentication) said about how to make a request then looked at the details of a verbose curl request to figure out the parts `curl -v --digest --user username:password http://url.com/api`. Here are the parts. You need to make a request, receive a 401 unauthorized, then compute an authorization header using MD5 sums based on the `nonce` and `realm` in the headers of the unauthorized request.

```
import (
    "bytes"
    "crypto/md5"
    "crypto/rand"
    "encoding/hex"
    "fmt"
    "io"
    "io/ioutil"
    "log"
    "net/http"
    "strings"
)

func digestPost(host string, uri string, postBody []byte) bool {
    url := host + uri
    method := "POST"
    req, err := http.NewRequest(method, url, nil)
    req.Header.Set("Content-Type", "application/json")
    client := &http.Client{}
    resp, err := client.Do(req)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    defer resp.Body.Close()
    if resp.StatusCode != http.StatusUnauthorized {
        log.Printf("Recieved status code '%v' auth skipped", resp.StatusCode)
        return true
    }
    digestParts := digestParts(resp)
    digestParts["uri"] = uri
    digestParts["method"] = method
    digestParts["username"] = "username"
    digestParts["password"] = "password"
    req, err = http.NewRequest(method, url, bytes.NewBuffer(postBody))
    req.Header.Set("Authorization", getDigestAuthrization(digestParts))
    req.Header.Set("Content-Type", "application/json")

    resp, err = client.Do(req)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    defer resp.Body.Close()
    if resp.StatusCode != http.StatusOK {
        body, err := ioutil.ReadAll(resp.Body)
        if err != nil {
            panic(err)
        }
        log.Println("response body: ", string(body))
        return false
    }
    return true
}

func digestParts(resp *http.Response) map[string]string {
    result := map[string]string{}
    if len(resp.Header["Www-Authenticate"]) > 0 {
        wantedHeaders := []string{"nonce", "realm", "qop"}
        responseHeaders := strings.Split(resp.Header["Www-Authenticate"][0], ",")
        for _, r := range responseHeaders {
            for _, w := range wantedHeaders {
                if strings.Contains(r, w) {
                    result[w] = strings.Split(r, `"`)[1]
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return result
}

func getMD5(text string) string {
    hasher := md5.New()
    hasher.Write([]byte(text))
    return hex.EncodeToString(hasher.Sum(nil))
}

func getCnonce() string {
    b := make([]byte, 8)
    io.ReadFull(rand.Reader, b)
    return fmt.Sprintf("%x", b)[:16]
}

func getDigestAuthrization(digestParts map[string]string) string {
    d := digestParts
    ha1 := getMD5(d["username"] + ":" + d["realm"] + ":" + d["password"])
    ha2 := getMD5(d["method"] + ":" + d["uri"])
    nonceCount := 00000001
    cnonce := getCnonce()
    response := getMD5(fmt.Sprintf("%s:%s:%v:%s:%s:%s", ha1, d["nonce"], nonceCount, cnonce, d["qop"], ha2))
    authorization := fmt.Sprintf(`Digest username="%s", realm="%s", nonce="%s", uri="%s", cnonce="%s", nc="%v", qop="%s", response="%s"`,
        d["username"], d["realm"], d["nonce"], d["uri"], cnonce, nonceCount, d["qop"], response)
    return authorization
}
```

Comment: Isn't it: "in the headers of the unauthorized response", you are meaning?

Comment: You get back parts that you need to use to make the request. You then have to use them to make the request, but it isn't just a copy and paste.

Comment: import (
 "bytes"
 "crypto/md5"
 "crypto/rand"
 "encoding/hex"
 "fmt"
 "io"
 "io/ioutil"
 "log"
 "net/http"
 "strings"
)

Comment: @mvndaai Hey thanks for this source code! I am wondering if you have written a test for this?

Comment: @JeffreyYong sorry the don't have the project that I made this for anymore.

Comment: response := getMD5(fmt.Sprintf("%s:%s:%08x:%s:%s:%s", ha1, d["nonce"], nonceCount, cnonce, d["qop"], ha2))

without %08x part it didn't work for me

Answer (score 1):

The `net/http` package in the standard library does not have support for [digest](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc7616) auth out of the box. However, a third party package may be used:

```golang
package main

import (
    "net/http"

    "github.com/icholy/digest"
)

func main() {
    client := &http.Client{
        Transport: &digest.Transport{
            Username: "foo",
            Password: "bar",
        },
    }
    res, err := client.Post("https://example.com/api", "text/plain", nil)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    defer res.Body.Close()
}
```

- pkgsite https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/icholy/digest
- github https://github.com/icholy/digest